# C++: What is the difference between ' arr ' and ' arr[] '

Tags: c++, arrays

A part of a program I am working on is to sort an array of ints, so I used the easiest algorithm for me, *selection sort*, to do so. When I checked the algorithm online I found that the argument of the function is `selectionSort(int arr[], int n)` where *n* is the size of the array, that will be inputted later on; so when I called the function in the `main()` function I called it as follows `selectionSort(arr[n], n)` and tried printing the array just to check that the function works and it didn't work - just printed the array without sorting. Then I just removed the squared brackets and it worked well.

Here is the code:

```
void swap(int *xp, int *yp){
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n){
    int i, j, min_idx;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
          if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            min_idx = j;
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n; cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];               //fill in the array
    }
    selectionSort(arr, n);         //Here is the point, if I write arr[]
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){cout<<arr[i];}
}
```

[Selection Sort reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/)

[The Problem I am working on on Code Forces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/160/A)

Comment: Technically your program is invalid, since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want an "array" that you set the size of at run-time you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes you are right but it works, don't know how though.

Comment: Some compilers allow it as an *extension* of the C++ language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `arr` in your function call, it will decay to a pointer to its first element, it's equal to `&arr[0]`. It will have the type `int*`.

If you use `arr[i]` (for any valid index `i`), then you pass the value of a *single element* of the array. It will have the type `int`.

Since the function expects a pointer (when declaring an argument, `int arr[]` is equal to `int* arr`), passing plain `arr` will work fine, but `arr[i]` will get a complaint from the compiler since you pass something of the wrong type. ***However*** depending on the type of the array, this complaint might be just a *warning*, and the compiler will pretend that the value is a pointer. This is wrong and will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and probably crashes). The lesson for this: Don't ignore warning messages from the compiler, treat them as actual errors instead.

And if you write `arr[]` (without any index) when *calling* the function, then that's a syntax error.